# CSS compatible en todos los exploradores?

Tags: css, firefox

Buen día,

Tengo el siguiente estilo en css para un botón y para un combobox, al visualizarlos en mozilla 57.0.2 aparece el botón en blanco y el combobox con las opciones en blanco. que debería agregarle o cambiarle para que sea compatible en este explorador?

```css
#Estilo_botón

.buttonBlue:hover{
 color: #FFFFFF;
 border-color: #003C6F;
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 100%, 50% 0%, color-stop(0%, #004b8c),
  color-stop(100%, #0069b1) );
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #004b8c 0%, #0069b1 100%);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #004b8c 0%, #0069b1 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #004b8c 0%, #0069b1 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(bottom, #004b8c 0%, #0069b1 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #004b8c 0%, #0069b1 100%);
 filter: progid : DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient ( GradientType = 0,
  startColorstr = #0069b1, endColorstr = #004b8c );
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


 /*ESTILOS DE COMBOS*/
 .selectorCombo {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 4px !important;
  color: #2b70b5;
  border: 1px solid #D5E2EE !important;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4.6px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  pointer-events: stroke;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent
   linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFF 40%, #E1E1E1 200%) repeat scroll 0%
   0%;
  font-family: "Georgia";
 }

 .selectorCombo .ui-selectonemenu {
  border: 1px solid #D5E2EE !important;
  background: transparent
   linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFF 40%, #E1E1E1 200%) repeat scroll 0%
   0%;
  width: 100% !important;
 }

 .selectorCombo .ui-selectonemenu-label {
  box-shadow: none !important;
  color: #0078D2 !important;
  font: 12px Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0% !important;
  padding: 6.6px;
  width: 100% !important;
 }

 .selectorCombo .ui-selectonemenu.open .ui-selectonemenu-trigger .ui-icon
  {
  background-image: url("../img/icons/arrows/arrow-up-small.png")
   !important;
  background-position: 2px 6px;
 }
 .selectorCombo .select-picker-error .ui-selectonemenu-label {
  color: #C6056C !important;
  padding: 8px;
 }
```

Comment: ¡Hola! ¿Podrías proporcionarme el código HTML y más del código CSS? Estoy probando y se me ve igual en ambos exploradores (Botón azul al hacer hover y combobox completo blanco). ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PREFIJOS CSS DE NAVEGADORES

Se llaman prefijos de navegador o prefijos comerciales (vendor prefixes) a un prefijo que se antepone a una regla CSS destinado a que dicha regla sea leída y aplicada exclusivamente por un navegador concreto (por ejemplo Chrome) pero no por el resto de navegadores. El uso de prefijos suele aplicarse a propiedades que se encuentran en fase experimental o que aún no se han convertido en un estándar

- -webkit- (Google Chrome y Safari)
- -moz- (Firefox)
- -o- (Opera)
- -ms- (Internet explorer)

Con los guiones.

Ejemplo;

```
.elemento{
  -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition:all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition:all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Saludos.